# Pre-Order Traversal of heap

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure as well as to Functional Programming. I am trying to traverse a tree in pre-order using:

```
(def tree {:left 7 :val 4 :right {:left 4 :val 3 :right 1}})

(defn preorder

[tree]

  (if 

    (nil? tree)(0)
    (let [v (:val tree)

        l (:left tree)

        r (:right tree)]

      (print-str (v (preorder l) (preorder r))))))
```

But I get the following exception :`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn` when I call the function (preorder tree).
Can anyone guide me in what mistake am I making.

Answer (score 1):

`(0)` attempts to call `0` as a function: parentheses aren't for grouping, but for calling functions (or macros). Instead, just write `0`. Similarly, `(v (preorder l) (preorder r))` tries to call `v` as a function. Instead, you probably want something like `(str v (preorder l) (preorder r))`.

Comment: Thanks I made the changes in my code but I still dont get the expected result.The Output is "40030000".Can you tell me if I am applying The logic correctly?

Comment: Your tree doesn't have a consistent structure. Are `:left` and `:right` just numbers, or are they subtrees? As is, you call your function recursively on 7, the `:left` of the root, and 7's val/left/right are all nil.

Comment: I am creating the tree using maps.:left and :right are subtrees.